# Swift equivalent of PackageInfo and ApplicationInfo

Tags: ios, swift, user-permissions

I am trying to get the list of permission my application has and also the list of applications installed on the device. 
I am familiar with ApplicationInfo and PackageInfo in android but not able to find anything for ios swift

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the list of installed apps in iOS.

And there is no list of permissions. You check each individual permission at runtime when needed using the appropriate API for the given framework.